# What is the folkloric origin of "el príncipe azul"?

Tags: european-folklore, fairy-tales

In Spanish, the folkloric character who would in English be called "Prince Charming" is known as Príncipe Azul, the Blue Prince.

The Spanish Wikipedia claims that the origin is from a Romanian folktale called, roughly, "The Blue Prince of the Teardrop," however, I can't find this folktale, let alone determine whether it's the true origin.

From what folktale or other source does this character come?

Comment: In Romanian, [Prince Charming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Charming) is called [Pretty/Beautiful/Handsome Fetus/Boy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C4%83t-Frumos). As for [Prince Charming from a/the tear(drop)](http://ro.wikisource.org/wiki/F%C4%83t-Frumos_din_lacrim%C4%83), it is a tale having a known author (as opposed to a folk tale having no known author), written by none other than [Mihai Eminescu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mihai_Eminescu).